# Unity 2D Took a screen capture but it show the previous screen capture instead of the current screen capture

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and I am facing a problem right now which is showing the previous screen capture instead of the current screen capture.

My code:
**Take Screenshot**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TakeScreenshot : MonoBehaviour
{

    IEnumerator CaptureIt()
    {
        ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot("*.png", 0);
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1.5f);
    }

    public void TakeAShot()
    {
        StartCoroutine(CaptureIt());
    }
}
```

**Screenshot show**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;

public class ScreenshotPreview : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    GameObject canvas;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        string url = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "*.png";
        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(url);
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
        bool imageLoadSuccess = texture.LoadImage(bytes);
        while (!imageLoadSuccess)
        {
            print("image load failed");
            bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(url);
            imageLoadSuccess = texture.LoadImage(bytes);
        }
        print("Image load success: " + imageLoadSuccess);
        canvas.GetComponent<Image>().overrideSprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), new Vector2(0f, 0f), 100f);
    }
}
```

Have anybody with solution can help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading screenshot at `Start()`. So it loads on the start of the game. I guess you are doing new screenshot later in the game. So to update your screenshot in canvas, you need to load it after taking new screenshot. Move code from `Start` of `ScreenshotPreview` to some other public method. And call this method after taking screenshot.